# After GLM Rotation object is not centered anymore

Tags: c++, rotation, glm-math

I'm trying to rotate an object like

```
Model = glm::rotate(Model, glm::radians(15.f), glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
```

it is rotating, but the object seem also to be translated (it is higher). But: the decomposed translation show that the object is in his origin (0.0f,0.0f,0.0f).

How can I avoid this?

**EDIT:** I altered my code. I created the object at the position it should be, not origin. Now I create the object at origin and try to translate it afterwards. It is the same result, but now I can see the result.

This is my rotation code:

```
glm::vec3 scale;
glm::quat rotation;
glm::vec3 translation;
glm::vec3 skew;
glm::vec4 perspective;
this->Translate(glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
Model = glm::rotate(Model, angle,vector);
glm::decompose(Model, scale, rotation, translation, skew, perspective);

fprintf(stderr, "Translation: %f, %f, %f\n", translation.x, translation.y, translation.z);
fprintf(stderr, "Rotation: %f, %f, %f\n", rotation.x, rotation.y, rotation.z);

this->Translate(glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -10.0f));

glm::decompose(Model, scale, rotation, translation, skew, perspective);

fprintf(stderr, "Translation: %f, %f, %f\n", translation.x, translation.y, translation.z);
fprintf(stderr, "Rotation: %f, %f, %f\n", rotation.x, rotation.y, rotation.z);
```

At first I want to see the values for position and rotation after I rotate the object at origin. Which seems fine, tho
The Values are:

```
Translation: 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000
Rotation: 0.000000, -0.130526, 0.000000
```

after that I use:

```
this->Translate(glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -10.0f)); //move backwards
```

and the values after that are:

```
Translation: -2.588191, 0.000000, -9.659258
Rotation: 0.000000, -0.130526, 0.000000
```

I don't know, why the X-values are also changed. Does somebody has an idea?

Comment: Can you clarify what do you mean by 'the decomposed translation show'? What is the origin of you object (center of mass, corner, etc)? I assume the problem is that you rotating object (for example cube) with origin at corner around axis X (because you using vector 1,0,0 as a 3rd param), so it rotates around edge, but not an axis.

Comment: I just  used glm::decompose(Model, scale, rotation, translation, skew, perspective); to print out the translation after the rotation and it shows: Translation: 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000 . Here is a screenshot: https://imgur.com/KlAEjJS

Comment: Do you know what is the direction of camera? From screenshot it seems axis Z. So try to rotate object along Z axis by setting last parameter of vec3 to 1: `Model = glm::rotate(Model, glm::radians(15.f), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));`

Comment: You're right it is the Z Axis. What must be done, that the rotation on any axis doesn't "move" the object?

Comment: Actually it is not moving, it is only rotating around corner. The simplest solution to rotate cube around center of mass would be to specify corners of cube not by coordinates {0.0, 1.0} (as I suppose you doing now), but by {-1.0, 1.0}. (Use -1.0 instead of 0.0)

Comment: That's odd. Because it is a plane and these are the vertices : `-1.0f, -1.0f, -10,
1.0f, -1.0f, -10,
-1.0f,  1.0f, -10,
1.0f,  1.0f, -10,
-1.0f,  1.0f, -10,
1.0f,  -1.0f, -10,`

Comment: If you use this coordinates, and rotation around axis Z shifts plane when you are using `glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)` with last `1.0` in `glm::rotation` then it is truly weird. Check other movements in your transformation matrix (maybe you first shifting plane somewere and then rotating, I suggest to try different orders of transformations).

Answer (score 0):

If I interpret your coordinates correctly, you have a plane at `z=-10`. When you apply a rotation about the x-axis (through the origin) to this plane, it will also move. What you need to do is rotate it about an axis that passes through your plane. You can do this by combining the rotation with two translations that move the coordinate system to your plane. See e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26961471/opengl-rotation-around-a-point-using-glm) for reference.

About the second part of your question: If you combine multiple rotations and translations, they affect each other. Let's consider the 2D case. If you rotate by 45° and then move along the (local, rotated) x-axis, the object moves diagonally. If you decompose the resulting matrix with glm, the decomposition assumes a certain order of matrices. While you calculated `Rotation * Translation`, glm will output the according values for `Translation * Rotation`. That's why you get different values than you expect. See e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22076364/1210053) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

No. Now I know my problem. When I use

```
this->Translate(glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -10.0f));
```

after the rotation, I move it along the Z-Axis on the object. Not the global Z-Axis. I just now have to figure out how to move an object on a global Axis.